# Player struct generates C2440 error

Tags: c++

I am getting the errors: 
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'const Player
error C2628: 'Player' followed by 'int' is illegal (did you forget a ';'?)
from line 5, `const int WIDTH = 1280`
 but I don't understand what I did wrong.

My declarations:

```
#include <allegro5\allegro.h>
#include <allegro5\allegro_primitives.h>
#include "objects.h"

const int WIDTH = 1280;
const int HEIGHT = 720;
const float GRAVITY = 1.5;
const float FORCE = 1.4;
const float K = 0.25;
enum KEYS{UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT, SPACE};
bool keys[5] = {false, false, false, false, false};

void InitPlayer();
void DrawPlayer();

Player player;
```

InitPlayer function:

```
void InitPlayer() {
    player.x = 0;
    player.y = HEIGHT - 20;
    player.vy = 0;
    player.vx = 0;
    player.fx = 0;
    player.jumping = false;
}
```

Player struct:

```
struct Player {
    float x;
    float y;
    float fx;
    float vx;
    float vy;
    int direction;
    bool jumping;

    void Jump() {
    if(!jumping) {
        vy = -15;
        jumping = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to put a `;` at the end of the definition of `Player`:

```
struct Player {
    // Stuff goes here
};
 ^
 ^
 ^
```